# Amortized analysis for incrementing fibonacci based integers

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci, amortized-analysis

Suppose integers are represented as sum of Fibonacci numbers instead of powers of two, so `100101` represents `F(6)+F(3)+F(1)=8+2+1=11` (we assume `F(1)=F(2)=1`). I want to increment an integer under this representation in O(1) amortized time.

I have the algorithm for incrementing: the intuition is that there should be no two consecutive 1 bits. So I would first set the least significant 0 bit to 1, and then starting from the most significant bit, if the number has two consecutive 1 bits, say bits i and i-1, set them both to 0 and set the i+1 bit to 1. Recursively do this until there is no two consecutive 1 bits.

I use the accounting method to do the amortized analysis. So for each increment operation I would grant k dollars, and each bit flip would cost 1 dollar. However, I am having trouble setting and proving the correct value for k. Empirically I think `k=3` could work, but I do not know how to go about proving that.

Comment: Are you allowing any of the possible representations for a given number? For example `11` could also be represented as `101000` (8 + 3). (This would be the Zeckendorf representation.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I am assuming I increment from 0 using this algorithm so there should only be one unique representation of each number.

Comment: @jbapple This was a homework problem by Jeff Erickson from a long time ago...

Comment: Would you please consider accepting an answer or else leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of how to proceed.

First, prove that every integer `n` has a **unique** representation in Fibonacci numbers with no two consecutive 1 bits.  (Correction, and the lowest bit is 0.  I'll call that bit 0.)  So you'll start with one, apply your algorithm, and wind up with one.

Second, prove that if the `i`th bit flipped during the operation, the representation you come up with will be all 0's in bits 1, 2, 3, ..., i-1.  (Correction note, I am ignoring bit 0.)

Next if the `i`th bit is a 0 before the flip, let's credit the cost of flipping it to itself.  If the `i`th bit is a 1 before the flip, let's credit the cost of flipping it to be 2 because you have to flip it AND the one before it.  (Except for the special case of bit 1.)

If the `i`th bit wound up a 0, then you will not flip again until after you have the sequence `...010101` preceding it.  You started at `...000` and the next number is `Fib(i)` so that was how long it is between those bit flips.  From this you can put an upper bound on the cost of flipping the `i`th bit from `0` to `1`.  (The upper bound is that it is always 0.)

If the `i`th bit wound up a 1, then you will not flip again until after you have the sequence `...101010` preceding it.  You started at `...000` and the next number is `Fib(i-1)` so that was how long it is between those bit flips.  From this you can put an upper bound on the cost of flipping the `i`th bit from `1` to `0`.  (The upper bound is that it is always 1.)  Between the fact that `Fib(i-1)` is smaller than `Fib(i)` and the fact that we are crediting 2 bit flips to this operation, this bound will be larger than the previous.

Summing the two bounds, you'll come up with an amortized upper bound for the cost of flipping the `i`th bit.  This upper bound *will* decay exponentially.

Sum your upper bound over all possible bits, and you'll have a upper bound on your amortized cost of bit flips per operation.  It will be a finite number. :-)

Comment: First, it's incorrect that if the `i`th bit is flipped, it will have trailing 0's, because using the algorithm 3 would be `101` and 4 would be `1001`.

Comment: Then your argument about when the `i`th bit is 0 or 1 is also incorrect

Comment: None of it works if you ever flip the lowest bit.  Starting with uniqueness because 101 and 1000 are both representations of 3.  But if you never flip that bit, the rest of the outline works.

Comment: If you keep the lowest bit 0, then you consider bit 1 the lowest significant bit, and you would flip bit 1 first if bit 1 is 0. I see how 3 would be `1000` and 4 would be `1010`, but what would 5 be? Using my algorithm we should flip bit 2 first since it's 0, so `1110`, which under my algorithm would become `10010` which is 6 not 5.

Comment: @jtsai You have to special case what to do with the lowest significant bit..just like you do in binary.  You reverse it, flip the next bit based on what happened with the last, then merge together paired 1s until the bit flips have removed all paired 1s.  So 0, 10, 100, 110 -> 1000, 1010, 1100 -> 10000, 10010, 10100, 10110 -> 11000 -> 100000.  And so on.

Comment: ok I see what you mean now, but I'm lost at where you said "so that was how long it is between those bit flips". What do you mean by "how long"?

Comment: How many times do you have to increment before this bit will flip again?

Comment: I don't see how that helps us with the accounting scheme, could you clarify a little more?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say "The upper bound is that it is always 0" and "The upper bound is that it is always 1"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the potential method and let the potential of a representation be the number of 1 bits in it. Then incrementing the lowest order bit increases the potential by 1, so it is still amortized constant time, and every carry is amortized free, since it releases one unit of potential energy by turning two one bits into one one bit.

Comment: I have not learned the potential method and would like to use the accounting method for this problem. Could you clarify how to do it using the accounting method?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some propositions and observations that lead to the conclusion that **k=3**:

1. The application of the algorithm consists of a single increment (from **0** to **1**) and zero or more triplet flips (**011** to **100**).
2. After runnning the algorithm it is guaranteed that there are no more **11** patterns within the bit pattern.
3. The increment is applied to either the rightmost bit, or the one at its left because they are not both **1** when the algorithm starts.
4. After the increment, a **11** pattern may arise at the rightmost postion or one position to the left of it. It may be both (**111**), but then the algorithm will choose the left one.
5. The flip always perfoms this sub-pattern transformation: **011 -> 100**, and so the number of 1-bits decreases with every triplet flip. Also, the 1-bit that remains after the tripliet flip only has 0-bits at the right of it, except for the right-most bit which might be a **1** (in the case the increment phase results in **...111**).
6. After the triplet flip the only place where a new **11** pattern may surface is two bit positions to the left of the previous occurrence. And so there can be a cascade of triplet flips going in leftward direction. This process is finite, because the number of 1-bits decreases with every triplet flip.
7. The algorithm is correct because the increment happens to a bit which represents value 1 (both Fibonacci numbers represented by the right most two bits are 1), and so the represented value increases with 1. A triplet flip does not change the represented value because of the Fibonacci property.
8. Except for the rightmost 2 bits, all other bits can only become a 1-bit by being the left-most bit of a triplet flip at some point.
9. The representation generated for **F<sub>i</sub>+1**, where **F<sub>i</sub>** is the **i**<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number greater than 2, always has exactly two 1-bits, including the right-most bit. This is because the bit corresponding to value **F<sub>i</sub>** is set at a moment when all other bits are **0**, except maybe for the right most bit. In case the right most bit is not **1**, then it will become **1** at the next application of the algorithm. So it is guaranteed that the pattern **10...01** will be produced, and its value is **F<sub>i</sub>+1**.
10. The number of increments performed to get from **0** to **F<sub>i</sub>+1** is obviously **F<sub>i</sub>+1**. The number of triplet flips to get from **0** to **F<sub>i</sub>+1** is **F<sub>i</sub>-1**. This is because increments increase the number of 1-bits in the pattern with 1, while a triplit flip decreases this number with 1. As **F<sub>i</sub>+1** has two 1-bits more than the representation for **0**, the number of triplet flips was 2 less than the number of increments.

#### Conclusion

For increasing **i**, the ratio between the number of increments and triplet flips for reaching **F<sub>i</sub>+1** converges to 1, since the difference of 2 becomes negligable. This means that the **k** in the question converges to 3 (triplet flips consist of 3 flips).

#### Demo

See [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reaya69c/) that applies the algorithm repeatedly, showing the bit presentation, the total number of increments and triplet flips, and their ratio. See how the ratio (very) slowly converges to 1.

The implementation of the algorithm in the above fiddle is as follows:

```
// Apply the algorithm once
var mask; 
this.bits |= 1 << (this.bits & 1);
this.increments++;
mask = (this.bits & 6) === 6 ? 4 
     : (this.bits & 3) === 3 ? 2 : 0;
while (this.bits & mask) {
    this.bits ^= mask * 3.5; // 3 flips
    mask <<= 2;
    this.flips++;
}
```

Comment: Could you give some feed-back on this answer?

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you leave a comment?